# How to combine 2 Solar panels for double A

Tags: amperage, electricity, solar-energy

Sorry I'm still a rooky in electronics so forgive me if I make obvious mistakes.

I have 2 small solar panels. 5v 160mAh. The 5v is alright for my project and I thought I could double the current by combining them. I read on the internet that I should connect them in parallel but I dont get the desired result.

All measurements are made under a lamp so not ideal conditions, I know. The Voltage stays the same at around 4.74V. But the current stays at around 0.06mA. Thats exactly what 1 Solar panel achieves. Not the expected 0.12mA.
[image: 2 panels in parallel]
[image: Single panel]

Answer (score 3):

It would be best if you tested the solar cells outside. Testing with a lamp doesn't provide the same intensity of light as the sun in terms of wavelength or lumens.

Your voltage is low probably because of the same reason. You're right about connecting them in parallel to increase the current, you just need better environmental conditions.

Good luck.